How to invite a user for a private chat
How  to  invite  a  user  to  a  Private  MO chat.
I  read the  following  but I  do not  know  how  to  apply it yet.
Your  help is  appreciated
https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3635/36688
I  have  to  go  to  chat. Ok  but  how  do  I  find  a  user? How  create  a  Private chat room? And  how  do  I  invite  the user.
In the  past I  participated in chatroom  because  at the  bottom of  comment it was  written "do you  want automatically  move  to chatroom..." But  I do not know  the  regular chat room invitation method.

There are no private chats on StackExchange (which hosts MathOverflow). The only exception is that moderators can create a private chat (which is still visible to other moderators on the site), but this is done for moderation purposes only.

As @AsafKaragila already mentioned, regular users can only create rooms where the conversation is visible to everybody. But users with enough reputation points can created gallery rooms - on MO this privilege is set at 1k reputation points. In such rooms, you can choose which users are allowed to talk.

BTW the posts you linked contains links to: How do I invite a user to chat? (Mathematics Meta) and How do I contact other users? (Meta Stack Exchange)

Since you wrote that you " do not know the regular chat room invitation method", I have tried to illustrate this in this chatroom.

@MartinSleziak  Thanks Martin  I  went  to that  room. any  way I  think 'enough reputation' is  needed to  invte peiople  and  determn  who  can  enter the  room. how  much is the  necessary  reputation?

@AliTaghavi If you're around - and have further questions - why don't we talk in that chatroom. Feel free to ping me here.

There are several questions here - so let me comment on them briefly. (This answer is mostly gathering things already mentioned in the comments.)
A very short answer to the question from the title is: If by "private" you mean something visible only to you and to the other user, there isn't such an option (unless you become a moderator). Some related feature requests: Should we request a Private Message system? and
Any way to send a personal message to another user?
Various types of rooms

Only moderators can create private rooms - the messages posted there are available only to the moderators and to the users that have been explicitly granted access to that room.
Even regular users can create gallery rooms - the conversation is visible to everybody, but the room owner(s) can specify who is allowed to talk. To be able to create such a room you need at least 1k reputation points.
Regular rooms (with no restrictions) can be created by a user who has at least 100 reputation points. Keep in mind that you can choose various parent sites when creating a room.
One can create a one-to-one room - using the button "start a new room with a userXYZ" in chat profile. They are basically the same as the normal rooms - but in the list of rooms they are located at the end (even after the rooms imported from comments).

See also: Is there a list of SE chat privileges, and the minimum reputation required for those privileges?
Inviting user to a chatroom
You asked how to invite a user to a room - one can find the information here:

How do I contact other users? (on Meta Stack Exchange)
How do I invite a user to chat? (on Math Meta Stack Exchange - this question has an answer that contains also some screenshots)
I have also left a few messages in chat related to this.

Or you could simply ping the user in a comment - and include a link to the chatroom in that comment.
